# RecyclerView with fetching from DB or REST API example

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create an app using material design concepts and I have my data in DB from server. I am planning to use REST API calls and I will be receiving information in JSON format.

I have some knowledge and experience in using ListView and there are options like CursorAdapter, ArrayAdapter etc. But since RecyclerView will be the future in android I would like to use it to create my app.

Can anyone point me to some example or sample implementing this?

When I checked the documentation I am not able to understand passing other data than a array.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    String[] myDataset = new String[]{"hello", "heyy", "treat"};

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The myDataset here is an array. how can I use the JSON output from my REST call? and also the implementation of onClick events.

Comment: what kind of problems do you have with the adapter?

Comment: I am clueless on how to pack data to be fed into the adapter @pskink

Comment: ok what Adapter's method do you have problems with?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple to use and easy to setup solution I have created

Just write

```
compile 'com.suhel.restadapter:rest-adapter:4.0'
```

in module level build.gradle file

For instructions on how to use it visit [Android RESTAdapter](https://forkachild.github.io/Android-RESTAdapter/)